# ASP code not processing after application migration to 4.0 CLR

Tags: iis, asp-classic, .net-4.0, application-pool

I have the below code inside a Footer which is a asp page. This asp footer page when rendered inside an aspx page does not process the below lines of code. This used to work in IIS 2.0 Application pool, but when I migrated the application to 4.0 App Pool this code is not getting processed. What could be the issue with my new App Pool or is there anything I am missing?

```
<%response.write("Copyright "&Year(Date))%>

<% if Request.ServerVariables("SERVER_PORT_SECURE") = 1 then %>

<% end if%>
```

Comment: Have you set the pool to use the legacy mode for running ASP classic applications?

Comment: Something about `ASP Compatibility Mode` in here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973813.aspx

Comment: I tried with Integrated and Classic. Both are not working.

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: The page loads successfully without any error message. But asp tag is not processed and the code visible on the browser page like <%response.write("Copyright "&Year(Date))%>.

Comment: see: [Classic ASP Not Installed by Default on IIS 7.0 and above](http://www.iis.net/learn/application-frameworks/running-classic-asp-applications-on-iis-7-and-iis-8/classic-asp-not-installed-by-default-on-iis)

Comment: "This asp footer page when rendered **inside an aspx** page...".

From this I take it that what you're trying to do is to use a classic asp page as an include within an asp.net page.  This won't work.  IIS will treat it as part of the aspx page and expect it to contain the sort of code you might find in an aspx page, it won't process server side VBScript unless you include it in a page with an asp extension.